# How can i make sure that there are no duplicate requests to fetch image from url in cellForRowAtIndexPath for a UITableView in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to make an instagram like table view to show images. I am caching images in the cache directory too.

Everything is working great, But whenever i scroll quickly and then scroll back up real quick, I end up making two requests to download the same image in the cellForRowAtIndexPath() method . Is there any solid way to avoid duplicate requests?

I don't want to cancel request when the cell is dequeued (I know a  lot of people seem to do that). However i am looking for a way where i can make one request if the image is not in the cache directory. Please let me know how can i do something like this.

Here is my code which i am using to pull the image from the url. Please excuse the poor naming of the variable. I am still testing.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0)){ [unowned self] in



                let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imageurl!)
                let imagefromURL:UIImage = UIImage(data: imageData!)!
                let imageData1 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imagefromURL, 1)

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { [unowned self] in

                    imageData1.writeToFile(getImagePath, atomically: true)
                    if let cellToUpdate = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
                        cell.contentImage.image = imagefromURL
                         cell.spinner.stopAnimating()
                    }
                }
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to keep status of all rows in `NSMutableDictionary`. This dictionary will be in single array and number of dictionaries in array should be equeal to the number of cells in the table.

Keep following keys in that dictionary:

- BOOL : isImageLoaded
- BOOL : isImageLoading
- String : Image name (This image name should be unique, and used
  to get image from cache )

Now, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, fetch dictionary object from array. `index` of array will be `index path` of that cell. Inside that cell, check the status `isImageLoaded` and `isImageLoading`. If both are false, then and then load image from url and change `isImageLoading` to `TRUE`. Once the image is downloaded, set `isImageLoaded` to `TRUE`. If you are caching images, then you should first check `isImageLoaded`. If it is `TRUE`, then get it from cache rather than downloading it in future calls.

We need this mechanism because cells are reusing memory. If you set property to your custom cell like `cell.isImageLoaded`, then there will be data mismatch and you will get wrong status on scrolling as cells are reusing each other's memory.

Hope it helps...

Please add comments if you have any confusion.

Comment: Thanks Pratik, Really good piece of Advice. What do u think if i set these properties on my PhotoFeed model. Eg. PhotoFeed.isImageLoaded since i am already storing an array of photoFeed objets. Or will that be a problem if new objects are added at the start?

Comment: Yes, you can try what you are saying, as we update the `photoFeed` object from array on `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` i.e. `index path` belongs to the proper `objectAtIndex` of array.

Comment: Alright cheers mate!! will give it a go and let you know how it goes :)